# Rendering images in angular server side rendereing

Tags: angular, dom, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to dynamically render images from an API call with angular ssr?

The base 64 image data pub.thumbnail is available:

> thumbnail data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB0IAAAPTCAYAAAAtvcoQAAAgAElEQVR4nOzde3xUB53//6FAr9qW3u+tllZbXatVV61f7Vp1dXWtWt1Vd1d33Z9u97vVr+tuV3cIgXAnKZQCQwgQoFDCpVAIFCgh3Mt1cuWeQCAhIQm
>   ...

But the following just renders "data thumbnail"

```
<div fxFlex="45 " *ngIf="pub.thumbnail as value ">
    <mat-card style="margin: 1em ">
        <img mat-card-image src="{{value}} " alt="data thumbnail ">
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Is this possible or prohibited by SSR? The rest of the page renders fine which can be seen [here](https://doi2.psi.ch/detail/10.16907%2Fe495cce8-59ab-4444-b12e-36b2160f6a98)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the generated html, it's because angular does not trust your image data

```
<img  alt="data thumbnail " src="unsafe:data:image/png;base64,iVBO.... ">
```

Try using angular's [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
{
    this.value = "data:image/png;base64....";
    this.value = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.value);
```

**Edit**:

You need to use property binding syntax in your template (`<img [src]="value"`), as indicated in the generated html

```
<img  alt="data thumbnail "src="unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding: 10.16907/e495cce8-59ab-4444-b12e-36b2160f6a98 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss) ">
```

Comment: again i just get the alt text displayed

Comment: i think i need to tell angular that i want this element to be rendered in the browser rather than on the server.

Comment: winner! [see](https://doi2.psi.ch/detail/10.16907%2Fe495cce8-59ab-4444-b12e-36b2160f6a98)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an `<iframe>`? Something like this:

**component.html**

```
<iframe style="width: 620px; height: 310px;" id="my_image"></iframe>
```

**component.ts**

```
document.getElementById('my_image').setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64, ' + value)
```

Supposing you have a base64 image, this will work.

Comment: unfortunately I just get an empty box